# Auto color seaborn stacked bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I am attempting to create a stacked bar graph as [shown here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html) in seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))

# Load the example car crash dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)

# Plot the total crashes
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="total", y="abbrev", data=crashes,
            label="Total", color="b")

# Plot the crashes where alcohol was involved
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="alcohol", y="abbrev", data=crashes,
            label="Alcohol-involved", color="b")

# Add a legend and informative axis label
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 24), ylabel="",
       xlabel="Automobile collisions per billion miles")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

I notice in the code that color is manually set in each `barplot`.  This seems tedious and I know seaborn has some great color palates to take advantage of.  How can I automatically set the colors for each individual series (stack) when making a stacked bar graph as shown above?

Thanks in advance

### Edit:

To respond to the questions below, here is an example of a stacked graph when I don't manually define the color for each series, with the code I used to achieve it.

[image]

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()

xtics = df.index.astype('str')
sns.color_palette("Set1", n_colors=6, desat=.5)

sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series1"], label="Series1")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series2"], bottom=df["Series1"], label="Series2")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series3"], bottom=df["Series 2"], label="Series3")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series4"], bottom=df["Series3"], label="Series4")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series5"], bottom=df["Series4"], label = "Series5")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series6"], bottom=df["Series5"], label = "Series6")

ax.legend(ncol=1, frameon=True, loc='upper left',  bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

ax.set(title="Different Color for Each Bars, Same Color for each series", ylabel="YAxis", xlabel="XAxis")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

**Here's something of what I'm after:**
The actual color isn't important, I just want them to be different for each series without manually selecting each color myself.  Note the `color=` in the code below.

[image]

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()

xtics = df.index.astype('str')
sns.color_palette("Set1", n_colors=6, desat=.5)

sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series1"], label="Series1", color="#000000")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series2"], bottom=df["Series1"], label="Series2", color="#004949")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series3"], bottom=df["Series 2"], label="Series3", color="#009292")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series4"], bottom=df["Series3"], label="Series4", color="#ff6db6")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series5"], bottom=df["Series4"], label = "Series5", color="#490092")
sns.barplot(xtics, df["Series6"], bottom=df["Series5"], label = "Series6", color="#ffb6db")

ax.legend(ncol=1, frameon=True, loc='upper left',  bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

ax.set(title="Different Color for Each Bars, Same Color for each series", ylabel="YAxis", xlabel="XAxis")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

Comment: Please explain the desired output better. You don't have to specify a color and let seaborn choose one for you. But note that in the absence of `hue=`, seaborn will choose a different color for each bar. Is that something you would want, or do you want all the bars to be the same color, but use two different colors for each stack level?

Comment: The code you show *does* make use of the color palettes via the lines `sns.set_color_codes(...)`. Hence I don't think it's clear what's being asked for.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're quite right, it does allow me to use color palettes for series but I would really prefer if I didn't have to manually chose the color from that palate for each series I add (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_color_codes.html).  If I create a barplot with one series, it automatically chooses different colors for each bar within the series.  I want it to do the same for different series rather than different bars.

Comment: @DizietAsahi, seaborn will definitely automatically chose a color for each bar; I want it to automatically chose a color for each series instead of needing to manually set it as shown in the docs: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_color_codes.html

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've updated the question to try to clarify

Comment: @DizietAsahi I've updated the question in an attempt to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use a list of colors and use a loop, or an iterator of said list and use it as such:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
N_series = 6
N_bars = 4
xticks = ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
df = pd.DataFrame({f'Series{i+1}': np.random.randint(1,10,size=(N_bars,)) for i in range(N_series)}, index=xticks)

colors = iter(sns.color_palette('Set1', n_colors=N_series, desat=.75))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(xticks, df["Series1"], bottom=0, label="Series1", color=next(colors))
ax.bar(xticks, df["Series2"], bottom=df["Series1"], label="Series2", color=next(colors))
ax.bar(xticks, df["Series3"], bottom=df["Series2"]+df["Series1"], label="Series3", color=next(colors))
ax.bar(xticks, df["Series4"], bottom=df["Series3"]+df["Series2"]+df["Series1"], label="Series4", color=next(colors))
ax.bar(xticks, df["Series5"], bottom=df["Series4"]+df["Series3"]+df["Series2"]+df["Series1"], label="Series5", color=next(colors))
ax.bar(xticks, df["Series6"], bottom=df["Series5"]+df["Series4"]+df["Series3"]+df["Series2"]+df["Series1"], label="Series6", color=next(colors))

ax.legend(ncol=1, frameon=True, loc='upper left',  bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
ax.set(title="Same Color for each series", ylabel="YAxis", xlabel="XAxis")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

[image]

**PS**

- why do you want to use seaborn when you don't seem to be using it in any way different than `plt.bar()`? In my example, I used `bar()` directly, but you would get the same output if you were to substitute with `sns.barplot()`
- you had a mistake in your `bottom=` arguments, you have to provide the sum of all the bars below to get the desired output